# WWW::Netflix::API program and hiding the consumer_secret key

Tags: perl, perl-module

I've written a Perl CLI program that uses the [`WWW::Netflix::API`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aNetflix%3a%3aAPI) module. It's finished and I'd like to release it but w/o exposing my consumer_secret key. Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have two options:

- Make the end users obtain their own Netflix key.
- Proxy all the traffic through your own server and keep your secret key on your server.

You could keep casual users away from your secret key while still distributing it with some obfuscation but you won't keep it a secret from anyone with a modicum of skill.

Proxying all the traffic would pretty much mean setting up your own web service that mimics the parts of the Netflix API that you're using. If you're only using a small slice of the Netflix API then this could be pretty easy. However, you'd have to carefully check the Netflix terms of use to make sure you're playing by the rules.

I think you'd be better off making people get their own keys and then setting up your tool to read the keys from a configuration file of some sort.